# please convert version 2 to version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=2
study(title = "SuperTrend ATR + RSI", shorttitle = "SuperTrend ATR + RSI", overlay = true)

//Mode
Factor=input(title="Super Trend", defval=3, minval=1,maxval = 100)

ATR=input(title="ATR", defval=7, minval=1,maxval = 100)

RSI = input(title="RSI", defval=7, minval=1, maxval = 100)

//Super Trend ATR
Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(ATR))

Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(ATR))

TUp=close[1]>TUp[1]? max(Up,TUp[1]) : Up

TDown=close[1]<TDown[1]? min(Dn,TDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = close > TDown[1] ? 1: close< TUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TUp: TDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red

//RSI
src = close,

ep = 2 * RSI - 1
auc = ema( max( src - src[1], 0 ), ep )

adc = ema( max( src[1] - src, 0 ), ep )

x1 = (RSI - 1) * ( adc * 70 / (100-70) - auc)

ub = iff( x1 >= 0, src + x1, src + x1 * (100-70)/70 )

x2 = (RSI - 1) * ( adc * 30 / (100-30) - auc)

lb = iff( x2 >= 0, src + x2, src + x2 * (100-30)/30 )

//Affichage

plot(avg(ub, lb), color=purple, style = line, linewidth=1, title="RSI")

plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend ATR")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use ta prefix before timeseries functions like atr and sma.You will have to use math prefix before math functions like min, max, avg.You will have to use color prefix before colors like red, green, purple. You will have to use suffix like int after input. You will have to declare time series variables before using them like TUp, TDown and Trend. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "SuperTrend ATR + RSI", shorttitle = "SuperTrend ATR + RSI", overlay = true)

//Mode
Factor=input.int(title="Super Trend", defval=3, minval=1,maxval = 100)

ATR=input.int(title="ATR", defval=7, minval=1,maxval = 100)

RSI = input.int(title="RSI", defval=7, minval=1, maxval = 100)

//Super Trend ATR
Up=hl2-(Factor*ta.atr(ATR))

Dn=hl2+(Factor*ta.atr(ATR))

var TUp=close
TUpL=close[1]>TUp[1]? math.max(Up,TUp[1]) : Up
var TDown=close
TDown:=close[1]<TDown[1]? math.min(Dn,TDown[1]) : Dn
var Trend=-1
Trend := close > TDown[1] ? 1: close< TUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TUp: TDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? color.green : color.red

//RSI
src = close,

ep = 2 * RSI - 1
auc = ta.ema( math.max( src - src[1], 0 ), ep )

adc = ta.ema( math.max( src[1] - src, 0 ), ep )

x1 = (RSI - 1) * ( adc * 70 / (100-70) - auc)

ub =  x1 >= 0? src + x1: src + x1 * (100-70)/70 

x2 = (RSI - 1) * ( adc * 30 / (100-30) - auc)

lb =  x2 >= 0? src + x2: src + x2 * (100-30)/30 

//Affichage

plot(math.avg(ub, lb), color=color.purple, style = plot.style_line, linewidth=1, title="RSI")

plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend ATR")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tradingview has an auto-convert function to pine v5 in the pine editore, on the right corner [image]